# How to bring in an html code snippet in gsp page using inline code

Tags: grails, gsp

when the value of i=0 or i=4, then I want to render the below code so that I can introduce a row.

```
<%--<div class="row selected-classifieds">
--%>
<g:each in="${shortAds?}" var="item" status="i">
<%
    if(i==4 || i==0)
    out << '<div class="row selected-classifieds">'
     %>

<div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <%--<img src="http://placehold.it/800x600/e0e0e0" />--%>
            <img height=100, width=100
                src="${createLink(controller: 'ImageProcessing', action: 'DisplayImage', params: ['id': item.id])}" />

            <div class="caption">
                <p>
                    <small><a href="#"> ${item?.title}
                    </a></small>
                <p>
                <p>
                    <strong> ${item?.price}
                    </strong>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<%
    if(i==4 || i==0)
    out << '</div>'
    %>

</g:each>
```

It is giving me below error message.
URI:/Classified/Class:org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsExceptionMessage:startup failed: C__SpringSource_ProjectClassified_Classified_grails_app_views_classified__adthumbnail_gsp: 21: unexpected token: < @ line 21, column 10. out <<  ^ 1 error

Comment: What is stopping to use [`<g:if>`](http://grails.org/doc/2.4.0/ref/Tags/if.html) instead?

Comment: Thanks for your response.How to make use of it in the above code?

Comment: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/if.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
<g:each in="${shortAds?.collate(4)}" var="itemset">
    <div class="row selected-classifieds">
        <g:each in="${itemset}" var="item">
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img height=100, width=100
                         src="${createLink(controller: 'ImageProcessing', action: 'DisplayImage', params: ['id': item.id])}" />
                    <div class="caption">
                        <p><small><a href="#"> ${item?.title}</a></small></p>
                        <p><strong>${item?.price}</strong></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </g:each>    
    </div>
</g:each>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answers. Here is how i used it. It is a workaround. It worked but I am kind of not satisfied.

```
<div class="row selected-classifieds">

<g:each in="${shortAds?}" var="item" status="i">
    <g:if test="${ i  == 3}">
        <div class="row selected-classifieds">
    </g:if>

    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="thumbnail">

            <img height=100, width=100
                src="${createLink(controller: 'ImageProcessing', action: 'DisplayImage', params: ['id': item.id])}" />
            <div class="caption">
                <p>
                    <small><a href="#"> ${item?.title}
                    </a></small>
                <p>
                <p>
                    <strong> ${item?.price}
                    </strong>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <g:if test="${ i  == 3}">
        </div>
    </g:if>
</g:each>
```